# Looking for a way to dynamically instantiate classes and call their methods

Tags: java, dynamic, proxy, rpc

1.Message.java this is javabean

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RpcMessage {
    String clazz;
    String method;
    List args;
    // get  set method
    public String getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }

    public String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }
    public List getArgs() {
        return args;
    }
}
```

2. have some class，these classes and the methods in the classes are what my remote end point may need to call

```
AA.java
   public void aa(){xxx}
   public int  bb(int a, int b)(return a+b)
BB.java
   public boolean isCCC(){return true}
   public String getMsg(String a, String b, int type){return "example"}
CC.java
....
```

3. If the processing logic is as follows

```
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //1. maybe http json string is：
        String str = "{\"clazz\":\"BB\",\"method\":\"getMsg\",\"args\":[\"args1\",\"args2\",5]}";

        //2. I use jackson convert json string to java class
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Message rpcMsg = mapper.readValue(str, Message.class);

        //3. reflect
        Class clazz = Class.forName(rpcMsg.getClass());
        Object obj = clazz.newInstance();

        //Here is my question, how is the parameter type here generated and passed?
        **Method method = clazz.getMethod("clickText", ???);**

        //There is also a problem with the entry here
        // public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args) 
        method.invoke(obj, **rpcMsg.getArgs()**);
     
    }
}
```

Guys, is there any way to solve my needs?

1. All sent by the remote end are json strings
2. The class and method I want to call may be arbitrary

Comment: Why don't you implement real RPC with REST API for instance. Your code here is using reflection. It is not a remote call you are doing.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know much about RPC., I'll learn the REST API you said

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) you should read on some popular implementation such as `SOAP`, `RESTful`, `gRPC` or `GraphQL`. But I will recommand you to start with RESTful.

I will suggest you this learning path:

1. [Client/Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L5BlpPU_muY) architecture
2. [Http protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview)
3. [RESTful architecture](https://www.codecademy.com/article/what-is-rest)
4. Start [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/) with RESTful